# VBA code for validating and formatting date input in text box

Tags: excel, vba

The purpose of the code is to format user input in a text box called `Zeitw` into a valid date format (`dd.MM.yyyy`). The code is executed whenever the user changes the text in the text box. The code checks if the input contains the date separators (periods). If they are missing, the code adds them in the appropriate places.

Next, the code checks if the date is valid by extracting the day, month, and year from the input string and checking if it can be converted to a valid date using the built-in `IsDate` function. If the date is not valid or if the day or month values are outside of their expected ranges, the text box is cleared and an error message is displayed to the user.

Finally, the code updates the text box with the formatted input.

```vb
Private Sub Zeitw_Change()
    Dim inputt As String
    inputt = Zeitw.Text

    ' Check if the input is numeric
    If Not IsNumeric(inputt) Then
        Zeitw.Text = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Add the date separators
    If Len(inputt) = 2 And InStr(inputt, ".") = 0 Then
        inputt = inputt & "."
    ElseIf Len(inputt) = 5 And InStr(inputt, ".", 3) = 0 Then
        inputt = inputt & "."
    End If

    ' Check if the date is valid
    If Len(inputt) = 10 Then
        Dim day As Integer
        Dim month As Integer
        Dim year As Integer
        day = Val(Mid(inputt, 1, 2))
        month = Val(Mid(inputt, 4, 2))
        year = Val(Right(inputt, 4))
        If Not IsDate(day & "." & month & "." & year) Then
            Zeitw.Text = ""
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.(tt.mm.jjjj)", vbExclamation, "Invalid Date"
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf day > 31 Or month > 12 Then
            Zeitw.Text = ""
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.(tt.mm.jjjj)", vbExclamation, "Invalid Date"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ' Check if the year is valid
    Dim minYear As Integer
    minYear = 1900
    Dim maxYear As Integer
    maxYear = 2099
    Dim yearValue As Integer
    yearValue = Val(Right(inputt, 4))
    If yearValue < minYear Or yearValue > maxYear Then
        Zeitw.Text = ""
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid year.(tt.mm.jjjj)", vbExclamation, "Invalid Year"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Update the textbox value
    Zeitw.Text = inputt
End Sub
```

The desired output is a properly formatted date in the text box that is valid and can be used by the program. The problem that the user is experiencing is that when they enter a date starting with a 0 (e.g. 01.03.2023), an error occurs. The error is

> Invalid Procedure Call and Argument.

Then in the end the debugger shows the line `ElseIf Len(inputt) = 5 And InStr(inputt, ".", 3) = 0 Then`.

Comment: What did you mean by `InStr(inputt, ".", 3)`? Was it supposed to be `InStr(3, inputt, ".")`?

Comment: The InStr function in this code checks if a period "." is present in the input string inputt starting from the 3rd position (i.e. after the second character).

Comment: Will creating 3 different text boxes for date, month and year not possible? I mean it will save you a lot of code, just curious.

Comment: Yes that would work but  i was already using 3 textboxes for every time period before and that was much easier to code .Now i would like to use  one textbox as a Date format  to make it look clear on Userform but couldnt properly do it  .Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @Blghn Then it certainly is supposed to be `InStr(3, inputt, ".")` rather than `InStr(inputt, ".", 3)`. Have you consulted [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function#syntax) for the order of the parameters?

Comment: @GSerg after correcting the order . My function is  working without any error, but unfortantly  couldnt get the output as desired.The current output is  (dd.mmjjjj). ,with a missing periot ,

Answer (score 1):

If the dots are optional then remove them before checking.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Zeitw_Change()
    
    Const minYear = 1900
    Const maxYear = 2099
    
    Dim inputt As String, s As String, dt As Date
    Dim ymd As String, msg As String, title As String
    
    ' remove any dots
    inputt = Zeitw.Text
    s = Replace(inputt, ".", "")

    ' Check if the input is 8 digits after dots removed
    If s Like "########" Then
       ymd = Right(s, 4) & "-" & Mid(s, 3, 2) & "-" & Left(s, 2)
       ' check valid date
       If IsDate(ymd) Then
            dt = DateValue(ymd)
            If year(dt) < minYear Or year(dt) > maxYear Then
                msg = "Year " & year(dt) & " must be between " & minYear & " and " & maxYear
                title = "Invalid year"
            End If
       Else
            msg = "Please enter a valid date (tt.mm.jjjj)"
            title = "Invalid date : " & inputt
       End If
    Else
        msg = "Please enter a valid date (tt.mm.jjjj)"
        title = "Invalid date format : " & inputt
    End If
       
    ' check result
    If msg = "" Then
        ' format with dots
        Zeitw.Text = Format(dt, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    Else
        Zeitw.Text = ""
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, title
    End If

End Sub
```